# BigQuery Materialized view: Query Limitations vs Creation Query Limitations

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

In the official guide, it names several limitations of BigQuery Materialized Views:
[https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#:~:text=Each%20base%20table%20can%20be,rewrite%20(or%20smart%20tuning)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#:%7E:text=Each%20base%20table%20can%20be,rewrite%20(or%20smart%20tuning)).

However I don't fully understand if these limitations apply to the creation of a view:
e.g.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW project-id.my_dataset.my_mv_table AS
SELECT #### THIS QUERY HAS LIMITATIONS ######
GROUP BY date
```

OR if there are limitations in querying the materialized view.
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM project-id.my_dataset.my_mv_table LEFT JOIN #### and some other complex query pattern ####
```

Does querying the materialized view itself (once created) has limitations at all that I should be aware of (or documented anywhere?). I couldn't find any specific documentation to it

Thank you all!

Comment: I've see it got a -1. Could you please add some direction so I can improve the question?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a bit more info around what limitations there are for materialised views in bigquery [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#supported-mvs).

In answer to your question, the limitations are for the query used in the creation of the materialised view and not when you're querying the materialised view.

Hope this helps!
Tom